# How to fetch value from custom multifield component?

Tags: aem, jcr

I have created a multifield custom widget having two fields with names ./urlLink and ./urlText.
Now i m trying to fetch the values from widget into the component's jsp with following code

```
String property = properties.get("./urlLink",String[].class);
for(String value: property ) {

  out.print(value);
}

out.print(property);
```

But i am not able to get its value instead i m getting error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a property and it contains a string value, you need to use the method `getString()` - that way when you have the property, you can set the string to the value by doing something like this:

```
Property property = properties.get("./urlLink",String.class);
String value = property.getString();
```

Just a side note, if your return is supposed to be a string array, your type that you're putting the values in should be a string array.

```
String[] value
```

Check out the documentation on [day.com](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/Property.html#getString%28%29) for Properties and getting the values inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo: you don't prefix a property name with `.\` when accessing it.

My guess is you got a `NullPointerException`, right? That's because there's no `./urlLink` property in the value map (`properties`). You should check against that anyway (so that it's not thrown on a fresh page with no content).

If that doesn't help -- double check that you have the properties in the content (call your page with `.xml` or `.infinite.json` extensions, and then double check if you can read them as plain strings (you should be able to -- CRX does some magic, smart type conversions).

Answer (score 0):

It's good to register custom xtype as :

```
// registering the custom widget with the name dualfield
    CQ.Ext.reg("dualfield", CQ.Ext.form.DualField);
```

Then u can easily fetch the value as :

String[] data = properties.get("multi",String[].class);

Here multi is the name of widget having multifield as xtype